# "Choose which You like" - Is "which" a direct object of two clauses?

Tags: relative-pronouns, direct-objects, which

I'm curious about the sentence: "*Choose which You like*". It seems that the relative pronoun *which* is the direct object of two clauses - a fact that the majority of English courses are quiet about:

a) Direct object of "Choose": *which* is the direct object of the verb "*choose*." It answers the question "Choose what?" And we answer by the whole clause, **so *which* substitutes for the "*You like*" clause??** I'm confused...

b) Embedded Clause: The phrase "*which you like*" acts as a little clause within the matrix sentence. Inside this clause, "*which*" is actually the direct object of the verb "*like*".

Ok... but I don't get one more thing apart of "which" substituting for the "*You like*" clause from example a): isn't *which* a kind of adjective here? After all, we can always say:

c) - Choose which (bike) you like? - *The red one*

We denote a color, not the alleged bike.

Comment: this is only my opinion, and not universal, but if I went to a bike shop, and the owner said to me, gesturing at the bikes "Choose which you like", I would get the impression he wasn't a local or native speaker or something.  "Which one do you like?" sounds ok.  It adds "one". And implies "choose".   It seems that "one" is usually in the sentence.

Comment: if "one" were omitted, it would still be implied, and so should be part of the grammar analysis.